# Is it possible to get previous stored value in Hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Let's say I have a hashmap.
`HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();`
Now I put some values in this map as below.
`hm.put("A","First");
hm.put("B","First");`

After this I again put some values for the already stored key "A".

`hm.put("A","Second");`

Now, if I try to get the value of "A" , I'll get "Second" as it's value.

`sysout(hm.get("A"));`

Output
`Second`

Is there any way to get previous value i.e. `"First"` ?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The value gets overwritten. It's not possible to get previous value. You'll have to implement your own logic to capture it.

Comment: I have been asked the same question and I have replied with this same answer that it is not possible as the value gets overwritten. But the interviewer said no there is a way to get the previous value.

Comment: Use the result returned by `put`. If it's `null`, there was nothing mapped to that key. If the result is not null, there you have the previous value associated with the key.

Comment: Why does your example have *two* initial `put` statements, i.e. `hm.put("A","First"); hm.put("B","First");`? Is there any relationship between those two mappings and the desire to get `"First"` as result? Do you want to get it because `"A"` formerly mapped to it or because `"B"` has been associated with it before `hm.put("A","Second");`? Or is the whole thing a trick question about the actual meaning of “previous”?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can however use a list as value. So it becomes:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = ...;
```

And then you can add or remove elements from the list to be able to retrieve previous values.

```
map.get(key).add(value);
```

This will add to the list in the map and when searching the most recent value, you can use

```
List<String> list = map.get(key);
String value = list.get(list.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you could do it in 2 ways :

1. Check if the value returned by the old `key` returns you a value
   (i.e `null` or not). Now you can capture that value before *putting*
   a new value to the said key.

   An illustration :

   ```
   HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();     
   hmap.put("A", "First");

   if (hmap.get("A") != null) {        
       String oldValue = hmap.get("A");        
       hmap.put("A", "Second");    
   }
   ```
2. We know that the `put()` method returns the value of the previous
   key

   > Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
   >   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
   >   replaced.
   >
   > @return the previous value associated with key

   So you could do :

   ```
   String oldValue = hmap.put("A", "Second");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know whether we can fetch the previous value that is currently altered or not as somebody told me that there is a way to get the previous value. Now my bad is I didn't get opportunity to ask him how. :(

Comment: *fetch the previous value that is currently altered* -- What do you mean?

Comment: Any way that `hmap.get("A")` gives me `"First"` after alteration (`hm.put("A","Second");`)

Comment: Yeah. In the above answer you are getting the previous value i.e `First` and then it gets replaced with `Second`. I suggest you to try it out.

Comment: Please focus ! I'm saying "after alteration" not "before".

Comment: You could try `String oldValue = hmap.put("A", "Second");` then. This way after alteration you get the previous value.

Comment: This is how I'd do it - either a `println` statement as mentioned or maybe store it elsewhere in some other `List` etc. So +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

to get the previous value you can assign the return value of put method to string

```
hm.put("A","First");
String temp = hm.put("A","Second");
System.out.println(temp); // prints first
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal map does not work that way. In a normal map the old value is overwritten and gone.

There is however a map-like data structure which saves a collection of values that has been put into the map: the [multi-map](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#multimaps).

Example:

```
ListMultimap<String, String> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();

m.put("A", "First");
m.put("A", "Second");

for (String s : m.get("A")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

// Prints:
// First
// Second
```

Multi-maps are very convenient to work with in a lot of situations, and they are well-worth learning about.

The example code here uses a multi-map from the Guava library. It can be downloaded from the [Maven Repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/27.0.1-jre/guava-27.0.1-jre.jar).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many Opportunities to achieve this, the question is how deep do you want save the values. Do you need also the first value after 10 put operations? Do you need it sorted?

You can achieve this in an unsorted way via a HashTable , see Java HashTable:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

```
Hashtable<Key, Element> table;
```

A sorted way could be, using a Stack or something :

```
HashMap <Key,Stack<Element>> values;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

So you can access the first element like this

```
values.get("A").peek();
```

If you have to access random Elements in the Stack, use LinkedList for this:

```
HashMap<Key,LinkedList<Element>> values;
values.get("A").getFirst();
values.get("A").getLast();
```

Be sure that you override always the hashCode() and equals() Method, if you use something like HashMap's.